# Did ancient Axumites use papyrus for writing?

Tags: ancient-history, africa, writing

Why are there [Ge'ez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ge%CA%BDez_script) texts only on rock and not on parchment or papyrus before the 4th century CE?

Comment: Please let us know where you have looked already. Questions which show prior research tend to get better answers. Thank you.

Comment: So I took a quick peek at that [writing system's wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ge%CA%BDez_script), and there's a picture of a [Ge'ez (papyrus) prayer scroll](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ethiopian_Scroll_comprising_prayers_against_various_ailments_Wellcome_L0031387.jpg#file) right at the top...

Comment: @T.E.D. That picture does not give a date for the scroll.

Comment: @kimchilover - That's a point. I can't find a date, but the Saint in question was a big deal on icons and charms, which would have had their heyday after the 4th Century.